# Trying open a specific folder in android using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to open a specific folder in android ?Is it possible to open a specific folder ???? this is the code i m using

```
    config=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cf);

      config.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
      {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            { 

            Intent intent = new Intent("Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT"); 
             Uri uri = Uri.parse("mnt/sdcard/myfiles/allfiles/download"); 
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*"); 
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "download"));


            }
       });
```

Comment: have you tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file

Answer (score 5):

It works:

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myFolder/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
startActivity(intent);
```

Have a nice codding :)

**EDIT**:
If the current solution doesn't help you, then  these file/directory choosers libraries can be helpful: 
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35

Comment: Error: No Activity found to handle PATH, Type="resource/folder"

Comment: Alauddin Ansari, maybe because you don't have any file manager app installed on your device. Please, check it.

Comment: I've "Root Explorer" installed on my device. Also there is default file manager. But still getting error.

Comment: this code is only work if you have ES file explorer. need to change the `setDataType`

Answer (score 1):

try to replace your code with this line

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
      {         
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            { 

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/myFolder/");
                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/csv");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));


            }
       });
```

Comment: i did the same bt it says u login in drop box app and the sign up

Comment: i just want to open a specific folder on my sd card

Comment: ya i am looking fotr your answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114408/how-can-i-use-intent-action-view-to-view-the-contents-of-a-folder..,see this link

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/adityak368/Android-FileBrowser-FilePicker)

The code :

**If you want open & browse file:** *FileBrowser.class*

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FileBrowser::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.INITIAL_DIRECTORY, File(storageDirPath).absolutePath)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.ALLOWED_FILE_EXTENSIONS,"*")

        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_INTENT )
```

**If you want to get user chosen file's URI:** *FileChooser.class*

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, FileChooser::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Constants.INITIAL_DIRECTORY, File(storageDirPath).absolutePath)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_INTENT )
```

Answer (score -1):

Pick root:

```
Intent selectFile = new Intent(); 
                             selectFile.setAction("com.sec.android.app.myfiles.PICK_DATA_MULTIPLE");    
            selectFile.putExtra("CONTENT_TYPE", "*/*");
            selectFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            startActivity(selectFile);
```

Comment: I want to set URI For this can you please help me ?