# How to show file chooser when button is clicked?

Tags: android, filechooser

I am trying to upload image in my app and i want to show some choices when my upload button is clicked. Unfortunately it gives me this error. I dont know what is wrong with the code. I got this from here[Trying open a specific folder in android using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544331/trying-open-a-specific-folder-in-android-using-intent)

[image]

thanks in advance!

```
uploadpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        openFolder();
    }
});
}
  public void openFolder()
        {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
         + "/Pictures/");
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "images");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));


    takephoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();            
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        profpic.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;


    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want the user to select an image, am I right? Then maybe a general file picker isn't whats best suited for your needs.

A quick google search came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507898/how-to-pick-an-image-from-gallery-sd-card-for-my-app-in-android) (also from SO). It seems like that solution is limited to pictures on an SD card.

---

**If you don't want to click the link:**

This is how you would start an `intent` in order to get an image.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
```

You'll then need to override `onActivityResult()`, but this is all described in the link.