# Open Specific Folder in Android with Click

Tags: java, android

I'm using the code below to open a folder created by my application but it's not working, though I got it from [Trying open a specific folder in android using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544331/trying-open-a-specific-folder-in-android-using-intent).

```
public void openFolder() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String pa = sharedPreferences.getString("path", "");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(pa);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder"));
}
```

When I am sing Action_View, it shows all possible means except `FileManager` and in `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` it took me to SAF mode like to choose storage and then specific folders.

How will it open my defined URI folder directly? Is there any other way?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String file= sharedPreferences.getString("path", "");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + file), "*/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.open_folder)));
```

Comment: It is giving error on intent.setData as we are giving string instead of file as required.