# Displaying image from gallery in Oncreate method without opening gallery intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I know how to open gallery intent and to display in the imageview.

But I am facing problem in selecting image automatically in oncreate method and display in the imageview.

I have an image in gallery folder with name "myfile.jpg"

Can anyone guide me how to do it without openting gallery intent.

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544331/trying-open-a-specific-folder-in-android-using-intent

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution :

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImage);

File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = root.getAbsolutePath();
path = path + File.separator + "myfile.jpg"; //where you image file located

Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Don't use bitmaps. Since you had image path with you, use `image.setImageURI(uri);` instead of bitmap.

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);` causes memory issues. Instead use any Imageloader like `Glide`, `Picasso` etc.

Comment: Eswar and Wizard , basically if i had imagepath then i use picasso. this is just an example.

Comment: Thank you very much Deepak Kumar, is it possible to upload this image to my webserver?

Comment: Can you help me with it? I have code which works in button click, sorry for trouble, I am newbie to android

Comment: use this https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

Comment: My image is stored in gallery and in camera  I am not able to do it on device its working fine in emulator