# Android: how do I get an Intent to open file chooser in specific folder of app's external storage?

Tags: android-intent, filechooser

I want to get my Intent to open a file chooser in a specific folder of my app's external storage, not the default 'Recent' folder, in order to browse files. My targetSdkVersion is 28.

I have read: [Trying open a specific folder in android using intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544331/trying-open-a-specific-folder-in-android-using-intent)
and 
[Android: How to open a specific folder via Intent and show its content in a file browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file/26651827)
both have helped a little but not solved my specific problem.

The code below in the loadSavedProjectAction() method takes me to the phone's default Recent folder not my app's /Documents folder.

The variable StorageDirectory holds the correct path which is: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.whereamihereattempt2/files/Documents

Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml includes:

```
         <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.whereamihereattempt2.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <external-path
        name="WhereAmIHereAttempt2"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Java Fragment class and relevant methods only:

```
public class SavedProjectFragment extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saved_project, container, false);

        Button selectSavedProjectButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.select_saved_project_button_id);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
        }

        selectSavedProjectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                loadSavedProjectAction();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //not implemented yet
    }


    private void loadSavedProjectAction() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        File storageDirectory = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), "com.example.whereamihereattempt2.fileprovider", storageDirectory);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open folder");
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
}
```

If it is not possible to open to a specific folder I guess I will have to create my own file browser, are there any good libraries for this?
Thanks for any help with this.